# lua lpeg expression to not sub in between delimeters

Tags: regex, lua, peg, lpeg

I would like to understand how I could `lpeg` to replace strings if they are NOT between a certain start and end delimiter. Below is an example, where I would like to use `SKIPstart` and `SKIPstop` to signify where text shouldn't be replaced.

```
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
```

to

```
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
new
new
```

Here would be another example with multiple delimiters:

```
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
```

to

```
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
```

and nested

```
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstop
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
```

to

```
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstop
rep
SKIPstop
new
new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know lpeg, but your task is easily solvable with usual Lua patterns.
IMO, lpeg or other external regex libraries are overkill in most cases, Lua patterns are surprisingly good enough.

```
local s = [[
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstop
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
]]
s = s:gsub("SKIPstart", "\1%0")
     :gsub("SKIPstop", "%0\2")
     :gsub("%b\1\2", "\0%0\0")
     :gsub("(%Z*)%z?(%Z*)%z?",
         function(a, b) return a:gsub("rep", "new")..b:gsub("[\1\2]", "") end)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
new
new
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstop
rep
SKIPstop
new
new
```

Comment: Might take a while for me to digest this.. but would it work with multiple delimiter? How about nested? What does does the `\1%0` mean? Just a little internal flag you used to mask the delimiter?

Comment: `would it work with multiple delimiter?` - Please add example of multiple delimiters to the question.

Comment: `Just a little internal flag you used to mask the delimiter?` - Yes, that's a workaround for impossibility to write `(abc)?` in Lua patterns

Comment: I added some more examples.

Comment: `would it work with multiple delimiter? How about nested?` - Yes. Yes.

Comment: I think I'm on the way to understanding it... can you please explain it though?

Comment: Which line of code needs explanation?

Comment: The first two `gsub`s are wrapping the delimiters with `\1 ... \2`, then we use those to form a boundary with the third `gsub` and wrap it with `\0`, then I don't get the complicated `"(%Z*)%z?(%Z*)%z?"` part.. I think `%Z` would match `\1|\2|...` but not `\0`.  but I don't see how we target captures outside of the delimiters.. or is `%Z` any character but `\0`?

Comment: I think I get it now. We capture two parts, a and b, which essentially capture every character but `\0` with `(%Z*)`. We don't want to replace anything after the first `\0` (which is b), so in the function, we only gsub on a. Then clean up the `\1` and `\2`. Very clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Egor Skriptunoff's answer is a great way of playing tricks with standard lua patterns to achieve your goal. I agree that if a straightforward way can work, I won't recommend using LPeg or other external libraries.

As you asked about LPeg, I'll show you how you can do it with LPeg.

```lua
local re = require('lpeg.re')

local defs = {
  do_rep = function(p)
    return p:gsub('rep', 'new')
  end
}

local pat = re.compile([=[--lpeg
  all <- {~ ( (!delimited . [^S]*)+ -> do_rep / delimited )* ~}
  delimited <- s (!s !e . / delimited)* e
  s <- 'SKIPstart'
  e <- 'SKIPstop'
]=], defs)

local s = [[
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstart
rep
SKIPstop
rep
SKIPstop
rep
rep
]]

s = pat:match(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Certainly, picking up the trick of using `%z`, which was formerly unknown to me, has already made things much easier. I will take some time to digest this and approve it as the answer. Out of curiosity though, i've seen tables be used in LPEG (pointers to sub-expressions). Why use the re.compile instead of a table? Thanks

Comment: I personally prefer using LPeg.re instead of bare LPeg, since it's easier to understand and write than plain LPeg.